# How to get the dialog popup to look like the preview?

Tags: codenameone

I'm used to java programming, but to CodenameOne not so much.
I've started a project with the **Social Boo theme**.
It's **not** a GUI project.
I managed to edit some text colour or the checkbox item look for example, but I simply can't get the **black Dialog popup window** like in the theme.res theme preview we see.
**Like this :**
[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsOzt.png)
I've spent a lot of hours looking on the Internet for an answer but I didn't find how to get it right....

Could anyone, please, point me to the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the default iOS 6.x dialog box since we switched to iOS 7+ style boxes we don't really use that design anymore as it's outdated.

You can download the [old iPhone 6 theme here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Themes/iPhoneTheme.res?raw=true) and look at the way we implemented this.

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
I manage to merge your theme with the Social Boo theme, because I could not extract the dialog borders pictures. and now it looks like I needed it to :D

Comment: Better - I found where were those images ! Thank you again !!